# How can I get data from a URL contains Arabic characters?

Tags: jquery, json, unicode, internationalization, blogger

In my Blogger website, I need to load posts from JSON feed, The JSON link looks like this.

```
http://technopress-demo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/LABEL NAME?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5
```

This is the code that I use to get posts from the URL above.

```
$.ajax({url:""+window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host
        +"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+LABEL NAME
        +"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5",
        type:'get',dataType:"jsonp",success:function(data){}
```

The problem is that when I change 'LABEL NAME' with an Arabic label the posts didn't load. I tested it with English label and it's working fine, but I have a problem with Arabic ones. I have tried this to decode URL but it's not working.

```
$.ajax({url:""+window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host
        +"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+encodeURIComponent(LABEL NAME)
        +"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5",
        type:'get',dataType:"jsonp",success:function(data){}
```

Comment: please try: encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/\*/g, "%2A")

Comment: @CarloLópezScutaro can you add it to the entire code because I had some error with escaping.

Comment: ok here you go, please try this one `$.ajax({url:""+window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host
        +"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+encodeURIComponent(LABEL_NAME).replace(/[!'()]/g, escape).replace(/*/g, "%2A")
        +"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5",
        type:'get',dataType:"jsonp",success:function(data){}`

Comment: @CarloLópezScutaro Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: please post the LABEL_NAME in arabics, it would make it easier to help with the full url

Comment: @CarloLópezScutaro for exemple you can use this LABEL NAME
أخبار.

http://technopress-demo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/أخبار?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5

Comment: This works for me:  `http://technopress-demo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1?alt=json-in-script&max-results=5`.  I got the middle part by applying `encodeURIComponent` to your Arabic string.  `encodeURIComponent` is UTF8-encoding your string, then percent-encoding each byte.

Comment: @JoeHildebrand yes it worked for me when I add it manually, But when it comes to add label dynamically depending on user input it doesn't work.

Comment: replace the "%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D‌​8%A7%D8%B1" part with encodeURIComponent(input), where input is what the user typed.

Comment: I do that but it didn't work.